# Google Drive API Error Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api, google-drive-realtime-api

Im getting error on using Google API.
having right to connect with Google Drive and add new sheet and insert data into it.

It was working till yesterday but when i run the application today.
Im getting error :

Error appears after users given token and tried to access the DRIVE API to get all the files

```
domain: "usageLimits"
extendedHelp: "https://code.google.com/apis/console"
message: "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."
reason: "dailyLimitExceededUnreg"
```

I have not changed any settings.
Following API are enables for my application access token. Do i have to add / enable more API to make it work.

[image]

Comment: Did you ensure that the OAuth Client ID that you're using is associated with the same Developers Console project?

Comment: Based from Google's reference, this error could happen when an application performs the requests without either apiKey(old api) or (client_secret, client_id). You will have `dailyLimitExceededUnreg` error if you were not granted access to the API during the preview phase and/or if you just make an API call without an API key or OAuth 2 token. Refer to this [forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube-api-gdata/6qrXtS1hTFQ).

Comment: yes both the client Id , client secret are the same in application and developer console
it was working fine day back and i made no change in oauth settings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was while getting access token. I was not providing correct scopes.
When i changed the scope to

> https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds https://docs.google.com/feeds
>   https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file

it worked fine

Comment: where did you define the scope? I have enabled API and I am still hitting same issue

Answer (score 5):

I was using NodeJS to download a file, but was forgetting to pass the auth.

Initially I was using:

```
function downloadFiles() {
  const service = google.drive('v3');
  const dest = fs.createWriteStream('/tmp/foo.csv');
  const fileId = '12345_ID_GOES_HERE';

  service.files.export({
    fileId: fileId,
    mimeType: 'text/csv'
  });
}
```

afterwards, I added an `auth` argument to the function, and passed it to the `export` method as well:

```
function downloadFiles(auth) {
  const service = google.drive('v3');
  const dest = fs.createWriteStream('/tmp/foo.csv');
  const fileId = '12345_ID_GOES_HERE';

  service.files.export({
    auth: auth,
    fileId: fileId,
    mimeType: 'text/csv'
  })
}
```

I am getting `auth` by creating an instance of [`google-auth-library`](https://github.com/google/google-auth-library-nodejs)

Comment: This is the correct answer, the issue is with the `auth` object.