# Unable to get file via Drive API in Node-Error:Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.]

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

Here is the full error:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "dailyLimitExceededUnreg",
    "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.",
    "extendedHelp": "https://code.google.com/apis/console"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."
 }
}
```

What I want to do is to download the contents of a particular Google Sheet to my desktop. I was following the Google Drive API documentation as outlined [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get#request) and [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads#downloading_a_file), so I have no idea where I am going wrong.

Here is the full code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var fs = require('fs');
var readline = require('readline');
var google = require('googleapis');
var googleAuth = require('google-auth-library');

var SCOPES = [
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
             ];
var TOKEN_DIR = (process.env.HOME || process.env.HOMEPATH ||
    process.env.USERPROFILE) + '/.credentials/';
var TOKEN_PATH = TOKEN_DIR + 'test-app-1.json';


fs.readFile('client_secret.json', function processClientSecrets(err, content) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('Error loading client secret file: ' + err);
    return;
  }

  authorize(JSON.parse(content), getFile);
});



function authorize(credentials, callback) {
  var clientSecret = credentials.installed.client_secret;
  var clientId = credentials.installed.client_id;
  var redirectUrl = credentials.installed.redirect_uris[0];
  var auth = new googleAuth();

   oauth2Client = new auth.OAuth2(clientId, clientSecret, redirectUrl);

  fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, function(err, token) {
    if (err) {
      getNewToken(oauth2Client, callback);
    } else {
       var token = token; 
      oauth2Client.credentials = JSON.parse(token);
      callback(oauth2Client);

    }
  });
}

function getNewToken(oauth2Client, callback) {
  var authUrl = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: 'offline',
    scope: SCOPES
  });
  console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url: ', authUrl);
  var rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
  });
  rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', function(code) {
    rl.close();
    oauth2Client.getToken(code, function(err, token) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('Error while trying to retrieve access token', err);
        return;
      }
      oauth2Client.credentials = token;
      storeToken(token);
      callback(oauth2Client);
    });
  });
}


function storeToken(token) {
  try {
    fs.mkdirSync(TOKEN_DIR);
  } catch (err) {
    if (err.code != 'EEXIST') {
      throw err;
    }
  }
  fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token));
  console.log('Token stored to ' + TOKEN_PATH);
}

function getFile(auth) {

    var drive = google.drive('v3');
    var fileId = '<FileId>';
    var dest = fs.createWriteStream('/desktop/test.xlsx');
    drive.files.get({
        fileId: fileId,
        mimeType: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
        })
        .on('end', function() {
            console.log('Done');
            })  
        .on('error', function(err) {
    console.log('Error during download', err);
    })  
        .pipe(dest);    
}
```

Comment: have you enabled the API that you are using? Kindly double check your Google Developer Console if it is enabled. Based on this [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35467945/google-drive-api-error-daily-limit-for-unauthenticated-use-exceeded?rq=1) you will get this error when you perform a request without any API key(old api) or (client_secret, client_id).

Comment: that error usually means that your GET request is missing an Authorization http header.

Answer (score 0):

You don't use `auth` in your code.
Also, you want a special format, I suggest using `export` instead.

```
function getFile(auth) {
    var drive = google.drive('v3');
    var fileId = '<FileId>';
    var dest = fs.createWriteStream('/desktop/test.xlsx');
    drive.files.export({
        auth: auth,
        fileId: fileId,
        mimeType: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
    })
    .on('end', function() {
        console.log('Done');
    })  
    .on('error', function(err) {
        console.log('Error during download', err);
    })  
    .pipe(dest);    
}
```