# How did i use google-drive.js to save file in drive with codeigniter?

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, google-drive-api

When I use google-drive.js example with my client id, to upload a file into my google drive, it works fine. But when I implement it into my project, built in the Codeigniter framework, it is not working and I get an error in response as defined below:

```
{
  "error": {
    "errors": [
      {
        "domain": "usageLimits",
        "reason": "dailyLimitExceededUnreg",
        "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued     use requires signup.",
        "extendedHelp": "https://code.google.com/apis/console"
      }
    ],
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use     requires signup."
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Drive API Error Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35467945/google-drive-api-error-daily-limit-for-unauthenticated-use-exceeded) or [Unable to get file via Drive API in Node-Error:Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36137875/unable-to-get-file-via-drive-api-in-node-errordaily-limit-for-unauthenticated-u?noredirect=1&lq=1) and a lot of others. Did you even try searching that error message first?

Comment: it means you haven't provided an access token in the http authorization header

Answer (score 0):

if you are face that in localserver your api configure works but that file not working ome where else then you just have to check that in url your localhost set as [::1] then change it as localhost because of that mismatch we get back return an error.

for ex. in google api configure we have set as http://localhost and in local it is replaced as  [::1] so google return an error.